# Store specific value in javascript when multiple forms are present

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I've got a list of 10-20 objects on each page creating these forms:

```
<div id="routeTable">
  {% for route in route_list %}
  <div id="routeDone">
    <form class="doneForm" action="/route/complete/" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="route_id" value="{{ route.route_id }}" />
      <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}" />
      <input type="submit" value="Done" class="doneButton" />
    </form>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

And I'm trying to add some jquery to the page in order to intercept the usual form submit and instead do so using ajax as below.  (I already have a view that returns an html chunk which will be swapped out for the above div#routeTable.  The problem is line 4 "var route_ID...":

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".doneForm").submit(function() {
    var route_id = $(this).attr('input[name=route_id]').val()

    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "/route/complete/",
      data: route_id,
      success: function(data) {
        $("#routeTable").html(data);
      }
    });
  return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Unfortunately I'm having trouble passing the proper route_id into the js variable named route_id.  I expect it will require use of the 'this' keyword, but I haven't been able to figure out exactly how.

Any suggestions on how to fix up my javascript would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change

```
var route_id = $(this).attr('input[name=route_id]').val()
```

to

```
var route_id = $(this).find('input[name=route_id]').val()
```

The reason being that `input[name=route_id]` is not an attribute, but a selector that represent a tag `input` and an attribute on that tag `[name=route_id]`.

You could also do

```
var route_id = $('input[name=route_id]',this).val()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var route_id = $(this).attr('input[name=route_id]').val()
```

Should be something like:

```
var route_id = $(this).find('input[name=route_id]').val()
```